# How to display multiple sets of data with reduce and promise.all in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making two calls from an API. I want to display the top results for airing shows and top tv shows. I have all of the data being returned from both API calls, but my code isn't efficient. I'd like to somehow take my returned data and display it in a single component (TopAnime) that will then map and return the information provided.

I figured reduce would be the best route, but I'm fumbling at this point. My thought process was to reduce the returned data from the API into an array. Take that reduced array and pass it as my new state and then have my component display it without having to write duplicate code. Both topTv and topAIring are showing because I've written the  component twice, but it's clearly not best practice to repeat code.

```
class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    topTv: [],
    topAiring: []
  }

  async getData() {
    const api = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3"
    const urls = [
      `${api}/top/anime/1/tv`,
      `${api}/top/anime/1/airing`
    ];

    return Promise.all(
      urls.map(async url => {
        return await fetch(url) // fetch data from urls
      })
    )
      .then(responses => // convert response to json and setState to retrieved data
        Promise.all(responses.map(resp => resp.json())).then(data => {
          console.log("data", data)
          // const results = [...data[0].top, ...data[1].top]; // data from TV & data from airing
          const reduceResults = data.reduce((acc, anime) => {
            return acc + anime
          }, [])
          console.log('reduce', reduceResults);

          const tvResults = data[0].top // data from TV
          const airingResults = data[1].top // data from airing
          this.setState({
            topTv: tvResults,
            topAiring: airingResults
          });
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log("There was an error:" + err))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <HomeWrapper>
        <h2>Top anime</h2>
        <TopAnime>
          {this.state.topTv.map((ani) => {
            return (
              <div key={ani.mal_id}>
                <img src={ani.image_url} alt='anime poster' />
                <h3>{ani.title}</h3>
              </div>
            )
          }).splice(0, 6)}
        </TopAnime>
        <h2>Top Airing</h2>
        <TopAnime>
          {this.state.topAiring.map((ani) => {
            return (
              <div key={ani.mal_id}>
                <img src={ani.image_url} alt='anime poster' />
                <h3>{ani.title}</h3>
              </div>
            )
          }).splice(0, 6)}
        </TopAnime>
      </HomeWrapper>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the response from API contains a flag called rank you can use the Array.prototype.filter to only show shows ranked 1-6.

[Working demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0vwj0q5mp)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TopAnime } from "./TopAnime";

export class HomePage extends Component {
  state = {
    topTv: [],
    topAiring: []
  };

  async getData() {
    const api = "https://api.jikan.moe/v3";
    const urls = [`${api}/top/anime/1/tv`, `${api}/top/anime/1/airing`];

    return Promise.all(
      urls.map(async url => {
        return await fetch(url); // fetch data from urls
      })
    )
      .then((
        responses // convert response to json and setState to retrieved data
      ) =>
        Promise.all(responses.map(resp => resp.json())).then(data => {
          // if you care about mutation use this
          const topTvFiltered = data[0].top.filter( (item) => item.rank <= 6 );
          const topAiringFiltered = data[1].top.filter( (item) => item.rank <= 6 );

          this.setState({
            topTv: topTvFiltered,
            topAiring: topAiringFiltered
          });
        })
      )
      .catch(err => console.log("There was an error:" + err));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  render() {
    const { topTv, topAiring } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        { topTv.length > 0 ? <h2>Top TV</h2> : null }
        {this.state.topTv.map((item, index) => (
          <TopAnime key={index} title={item.title} image={item.image_url} />
        ))}
        { topAiring.length > 0 ? <h2>Top airing</h2> : null }
        {this.state.topAiring.map((item, index) => (
          <TopAnime key={index} title={item.title} image={item.image_url} />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This puts me in the right direction, but the crutch of not knowing if it's topTv or topAiring is big. My goal is to show the top 6 results for each and have them labeled for the user.

Comment: Aha. I've updated my answer to only show the top ranked shows and the results are now separated into topTv and topAiring

Comment: I really do appreciate it! Thank you for adding in the comment about mutation as well.